# Can't Connect to my Local SQL Server Instance in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installed on Small Business Server 2011.  I'm having trouble connecting to my local SQL Instance through Management Studio.  No matter what I try, I'm getting this message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found or
>   was not accessible.  Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Proveder, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

I found a few articles on SO and elsewhere that advised me to look at Config Manager, make sure SQL Server Browser is running, and to glean my Server Name from there.  But, no matter what I try (`localhost`, `(local)`, `SQLEXPRESS`, `./SQLEXPRESS`, `(local)/SQLEXPRESS`, `SHAREPOINT`, `./SHAREPOINT`, `(local)/SHAREPOINT`, etc) I get the same message.  I can't figure out the magic words to make Management Studio connect to my local SQL instance.

FWIW: Here's what I'm getting out of Config Manager:
[image]

Comment: I think you have your slashes backwards,

Comment: @jmoerdyk - Oh, good lord!  Thanks!  If you wanna post that as the answer, I'll gladly upvote and accept.

Comment: ...at least until it gets closed because I'm stupid.

Answer (score 3):

Try writing the server as follow:

Machinename\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Yeah, I was able to connect using `.\SQLEXPRESS`. I'm sort of curious though... how come NOW I have to use the machine name?  I've installed SQL Server dozens of times before, and `localhost` was always more than sufficient.

Comment: There is 4 way: ip - machinename - (localhost) - . (Point = localhost)

Answer (score 0):

If you click on SQL Server Network Configuration, do you have Named Pipes Enabled under Protocols for SQLEXPRESS?  In an instance I have installed, I have TCP/IP, Shared Memory and Named Pipes all enabled.

Comment: No, I had my slashes backwards.  It's `.\SQLEXPRESS` rather than `./SQLEXPRESS`.  I'm a flipping idiot.